# Delete Duplicate Rows in Large Sqlite Table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table of 10million rows

I have duplicate rows and I've developed a column that concentrates several columns. This created column should be unique.

So this is what I have

```
col1    col2    col3    ...   col50
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
2       sam     blue          1samblue
3       fox     pink          3foxpink
```

what I want

```
col1    col2    col3    ...   col50
1       jim     red           1jimred
2       sam     blue          1samblue
3       fox     pink          3foxpink
```

I want to write a program that will delete the rows with duplicates found in col50 and retain all the other columns.

However I think 9million of the 10million rows are unique so I can't store the results in memory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't have just `CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM source_table; DELETE FROM source_table; INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table`?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be doable in pure SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM source_table;
DELETE FROM source_table; 
INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. Added another line to delete temp_table as well from .db and made it python compatible:

#To keep only unique rows in SQLITE3 database
conn = connect_to_db("/path/to/dbfile.db")
c = conn.cursor()   
c.executescript(""" 
    CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM source_table; 
    DELETE FROM source_table;
    INSERT INTO source_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
    DROP TABLE temp_table
    """)
conn.close()

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from TABLE where id in (
    select TABLE.id from TABLE q1
      join TABLE q2 on q1.name = q2.name
    where q1.id < q2.id)
```