# Pandas to read and large database and write it back afterwards

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a large .db file with pandas and SQL, but its using a lot of ram and taking a very large amount of time to complete.

The .db file has more than 5 million lines.

How can I do the same as bellow, but with less ram and in a quicker way?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3, shutil, glob, os
from pathlib import Path

#create folder if doesn't exist
NewFolderPath  = r"C:\Databases\\"
isFile = os.path.exists(NewFolderPath)
if isFile is False:
    Path(NewFolderPath).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

df = pd.DataFrame()

#SQL Connect
conn = sqlite3.connect(NewFolderPath+'hist_prices.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#dest = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
#conn.backup(dest)
conn.commit()

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from hist_prices", conn)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="last", inplace=True)
df.to_sql('hist_prices', conn,  if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Try Dask: https://dask.org/  for data-frame parrallel computing. You could load the data-frame in chunks too.

Comment: dask or vaex. But it doesn't seem to be that 5M could be considered large. How long is it taking?

Comment: What is the best way to use chunks?

Comment: if all you need is to remove completely duplicate rows you don't need the detour to pandas and back to sqlite: just `select distinct * from hist_prices` in sqlite, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48457018/3944322